# Looking up rows in csv file for an index column and pasting the corresponding values to a line under it using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

My title is confusing so I'll try to elaborate. I have a set of data that essentially a side-by-side display of similar entities and I'm trying to get the data from the right side of the spreadsheet under its corresponding column on the left.

[Sample data from the spreadsheet that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqbbP.png)

[And this is what I've been trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGcjR.png)

[This is what my output currently looks like on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6082.png)

````
```import csv
import pandas as pd

df2 = df.copy()
def target(index_of_file):
    index = index_of_file
    for index3 in df2.index:
        print(df2['ID2'][index3],df['Name2'][index3], df['Address2'][index3],
          df['Country2'][index3])

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

for index in df.index:
    print(df['ID1'][index], ",", df['Name1'][index], ",", df['Address1'][index], ",",df['Country1'][index])
    Targetindex = df['ID1']
    target(Targetindex)```
````

I realised that the way I'm handling index is not correct and that is essentially where my code becomes a mess. Any inputs would definitely be a learning experience for me. Thanks in advance

| ID1 | Name1 | Country1 | Address1 | ID | Name2 | Country2 | Address2 | Score | City_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1125874-STONETURN | UNITED STATES | 75 State St Ste 902 | 3 | 1125874-STONETURN | UNITED STATES | 75 State St Ste 902 | 100 | 100 |
| 10 | 1282357-VIMO | UNITED STATES | 2595 E Bayshore Rd Ste 250 | 11 | 1282357-VIMO | UNITED STATES | 2595 E Bayshore Rd Ste 250 | 100 | 100 |
| 14 | 1296837-INFRAHEALTH | UNITED STATES | 8705 Shoal Creek Blvd Ste 112 | 15 | 1296837-INFRAHEALTH | UNITED STATES | 8705 Shoal Creek Blvd Ste 112 | 100 | 100 |
| 17 | 1297217-BLAZE | UNITED STATES | 81 Larkfield Rd | 18 | 1297217-BLAZE | UNITED STATES | 81 Larkfield Rd | 100 | 100 |
| 24 | 1330177-AWSCUSTOMER1 | UNITED STATES | 112 E Pecan St | 25 | 1330177-AWSCUSTOMER2 | UNITED STATES | 112 E Pecan St | 83 | 100 |
| 27 | 1336739-FLEXTRADE-VMC-AWS | UNITED STATES | 111 Great Neck Rd | 28 | 1336739-FLEXTRADE-VMC-AWS | UNITED STATES | 111 Great Neck Rd | 100 | 100 |
| 58 | 5719679-ITACA TECH | UNITED STATES | 1395 Brickell Ave Ste 800 | 62 | 5719679-ITACA TECH | UNITED STATES | 1395 Brickell Ave Ste 800 | 100 | 100 |
| 58 | 5719679-ITACA TECH | UNITED STATES | 1395 Brickell Ave Ste 800 | 61 | 5719679-ITACA TECH | UNITED STATES | 1395 Brickell Ave Ste 800 | 100 | 100 |
| 58 | 5719679-ITACA TECH | UNITED STATES | 1395 Brickell Ave Ste 800 | 60 | 5719679-ITACA TECH | UNITED STATES | 1395 Brickell Ave Ste 800 | 100 | 100 |
| 58 | 5719679-ITACA TECH | UNITED STATES | 1395 Brickell Ave Ste 800 | 59 | 5719679-ITACA TECH | UNITED STATES | 1395 Brickell Ave Ste 800 | 100 | 100 |

Comment: Can you please provide some programable data? Screenshots are not an acceptable form of data sharing as it prevents copy/paste for troubleshooting

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn HI. Sorry yes, this is my first time posting so it took me some time to figure out how to make a table.